# Last UIButton is unresponsive in UIStackView

Tags: swift, uistackview

I have programmatically added `UIStackView` to the `UIViewcontroller's view` and added further buttons and labels as sub arranged view to stackview, but the last added button is not responding.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    addSubview(contentStackView)
    contentStackView.fillSuperviewHorizontally()
    contentStackView.topAnchor ~ topAnchor
    contentStackView.bottomAnchor ~ bottomAnchor | .other(.defaultLow - 1)

    contentStackView.addArrangedSubview(restorePurchaseButton)
    if !isPhone {
        contentStackView.setCustomSpacing(40, after: restorePurchaseButton)
    }
    contentStackView.addArrangedSubview(taxesLabel)
    contentStackView.addArrangedSubview(descriptionLabel)
    contentStackView.addArrangedSubview(UIStackView(axis: .vertical, arrangedSubviews: [contactUsLabel, supportButton]))
    contentStackView.addArrangedSubview(backToTopButton)
    backToTopButton.backgroundColor = .red
    contentStackView.backgroundColor = .green
}
```

`Back to top` button is unresponsive but it is visible on the device.
This is how it is created:

```
private lazy var backToTopButton: UIButton = {
       let button = UIButton(type: .system)
       button.apply(styles: Style.subscriptionFooterButton)
       setButtonAttributedText(L10n.button.backToTop, for: button)
       button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backToTopDidTap(_:)), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
       return button
 }()

lazy var contentStackView: UIStackView = {
       let stackView = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
       stackView.axis = .vertical
       stackView.spacing = 24
       stackView.alignment = .center
       return stackView
}()
```

if I change the position of buttons then it would work, i.e if I keep `back to top` button above `contactus` , `backToTop` starts working and `contact us` doesn't respond.

Comment: Try Kerem' suggestion of setting all your views' `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false`. If that doesn't solve the problem, try using the Xcode view debugger to look at your view hierarchy. (Look for the button with the hint "Debug View Hierarchy" at the top of the debug area.) One of your buttons might be outside of it's parent view's bounds, which could prevent taps from getting to it.

Comment: *"... programmatically added `UIStackView` to the `UIViewcontroller`'s view ..."* -- It is rather unusual to implement `override init(frame: CGRect)` in the "`UIViewcontroller`'s view" -- Is this code actually in a custom view class?